# (Facebook Login Api) I want to change the account to log in to when logging in

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I want to remove all previously logged in information from the associated Android Studio sdk Facebook Login API and log in with a different ID. Is there a way??
The data for the first login account still remains, so it seems that you can only log in with that ID after that.
Even if you delete the token or log out, you can log in only with the information you logged in for the first time.

The development environment is Android SDK.

Tried deleting the token or logging out using Java HttpURLConnection.

Here is the code to delete the token.

```
     GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/me/permissions/",
                    parameters,
                    HttpMethod.DELETE,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            // Insert your code here
                        }
                    });

            request.executeAsync();
```

This will take you to a page that asks for permission, but won't ask for a login ID and password.